# Why is the total query time so much longer than the single shard time in Elastic Search?

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, time

es version:7.3.2.

The total query time so much longer than the single shard time.
This problem can only occur if the same piece of data has not been requested for a long time, and then the data is requested now.
This problem also disappears when data is no longer written to the index in real time.
I would like to know how to troubleshoot this problem.
Thanks!

request:

```
GET friend_relation_realtime_v2/_search?human=true {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "user_id": "544799000"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

result:

```
{
  "took" : 1277,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 10,
    "successful" : 10,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 233,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [
     .........
    ]
  },
  "profile" : {
    "shards" : [
      {
        "id" : "[2mYeMFE1RO2Uu2pi63sMNQ][friend_relation_realtime_v2][3]",
        "searches" : [
          {
            "query" : [
              {
                "type" : "BoostQuery",
                "description" : "(ConstantScore(user_id:544799000))^0.0",
                "time" : "315.2micros",
                "time_in_nanos" : 315291,
                "breakdown" : {
                  "set_min_competitive_score_count" : 0,
                  "match_count" : 0,
                  "shallow_advance_count" : 0,
                  "set_min_competitive_score" : 0,
                  "next_doc" : 4262,
                  "match" : 0,
                  "next_doc_count" : 19,
                  "score_count" : 19,
                  "compute_max_score_count" : 0,
                  "compute_max_score" : 0,
                  "advance" : 10573,
                  "advance_count" : 3,
                  "score" : 1339,
                  "build_scorer_count" : 26,
                  "create_weight" : 5623,
                  "shallow_advance" : 0,
                  "create_weight_count" : 1,
                  "build_scorer" : 293426
                },
                "children" : [
                  {
                    "type" : "TermQuery",
                    "description" : "user_id:544799000",
                    "time" : "301.4micros",
                    "time_in_nanos" : 301455,
                    "breakdown" : {
                      "set_min_competitive_score_count" : 0,
                      "match_count" : 0,
                      "shallow_advance_count" : 0,
                      "set_min_competitive_score" : 0,
                      "next_doc" : 1582,
                      "match" : 0,
                      "next_doc_count" : 19,
                      "score_count" : 0,
                      "compute_max_score_count" : 0,
                      "compute_max_score" : 0,
                      "advance" : 9888,
                      "advance_count" : 3,
                      "score" : 0,
                      "build_scorer_count" : 26,
                      "create_weight" : 2994,
                      "shallow_advance" : 0,
                      "create_weight_count" : 1,
                      "build_scorer" : 286942
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "rewrite_time" : 2381,
            "collector" : [
              {
                "name" : "CancellableCollector",
                "reason" : "search_cancelled",
                "time" : "19micros",
                "time_in_nanos" : 19029,
                "children" : [
                  {
                    "name" : "SimpleTopScoreDocCollector",
                    "reason" : "search_top_hits",
                    "time" : "9.1micros",
                    "time_in_nanos" : 9134
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "aggregations" : [ ]
      },
      {
        "id" : "[2mYeMFE1RO2Uu2pi63sMNQ][friend_relation_realtime_v2][4]",
        "searches" : [
          {
            "query" : [
              {
                "type" : "BoostQuery",
                "description" : "(ConstantScore(user_id:544799000))^0.0",
                "time" : "320.9micros",
                "time_in_nanos" : 320910,
                "breakdown" : {
                  "set_min_competitive_score_count" : 0,
                  "match_count" : 0,
                  "shallow_advance_count" : 0,
                  "set_min_competitive_score" : 0,
                  "next_doc" : 4158,
                  "match" : 0,
                  "next_doc_count" : 24,
                  "score_count" : 24,
                  "compute_max_score_count" : 0,
                  "compute_max_score" : 0,
                  "advance" : 9283,
                  "advance_count" : 2,
                  "score" : 1345,
                  "build_scorer_count" : 31,
                  "create_weight" : 10394,
                  "shallow_advance" : 0,
                  "create_weight_count" : 1,
                  "build_scorer" : 295648
                },
                "children" : [
                  {
                    "type" : "TermQuery",
                    "description" : "user_id:544799000",
                    "time" : "298.3micros",
                    "time_in_nanos" : 298395,
                    "breakdown" : {
                      "set_min_competitive_score_count" : 0,
                      "match_count" : 0,
                      "shallow_advance_count" : 0,
                      "set_min_competitive_score" : 0,
                      "next_doc" : 1811,
                      "match" : 0,
                      "next_doc_count" : 24,
                      "score_count" : 0,
                      "compute_max_score_count" : 0,
                      "compute_max_score" : 0,
                      "advance" : 8764,
                      "advance_count" : 2,
                      "score" : 0,
                      "build_scorer_count" : 31,
                      "create_weight" : 3754,
                      "shallow_advance" : 0,
                      "create_weight_count" : 1,
                      "build_scorer" : 284008
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "rewrite_time" : 4100,
            "collector" : [
              {
                "name" : "CancellableCollector",
                "reason" : "search_cancelled",
                "time" : "33.7micros",
                "time_in_nanos" : 33781,
                "children" : [
                  {
                    "name" : "SimpleTopScoreDocCollector",
                    "reason" : "search_top_hits",
                    "time" : "10.2micros",
                    "time_in_nanos" : 10214
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "aggregations" : [ ]
      },
      {
        "id" : "[I0cNQW50Q3C_kt28KVSVsQ][friend_relation_realtime_v2][1]",
        "searches" : [
          {
            "query" : [
              {
                "type" : "BoostQuery",
                "description" : "(ConstantScore(user_id:544799000))^0.0",
                "time" : "384.6micros",
                "time_in_nanos" : 384608,
                "breakdown" : {
                  "set_min_competitive_score_count" : 0,
                  "match_count" : 0,
                  "shallow_advance_count" : 0,
                  "set_min_competitive_score" : 0,
                  "next_doc" : 5840,
                  "match" : 0,
                  "next_doc_count" : 33,
                  "score_count" : 31,
                  "compute_max_score_count" : 0,
                  "compute_max_score" : 0,
                  "advance" : 27664,
                  "advance_count" : 4,
                  "score" : 1749,
                  "build_scorer_count" : 26,
                  "create_weight" : 19208,
                  "shallow_advance" : 0,
                  "create_weight_count" : 1,
                  "build_scorer" : 330052
                },
                "children" : [
                  {
                    "type" : "TermQuery",
                    "description" : "user_id:544799000",
                    "time" : "338.5micros",
                    "time_in_nanos" : 338550,
                    "breakdown" : {
                      "set_min_competitive_score_count" : 0,
                      "match_count" : 0,
                      "shallow_advance_count" : 0,
                      "set_min_competitive_score" : 0,
                      "next_doc" : 2227,
                      "match" : 0,
                      "next_doc_count" : 33,
                      "score_count" : 0,
                      "compute_max_score_count" : 0,
                      "compute_max_score" : 0,
                      "advance" : 24780,
                      "advance_count" : 4,
                      "score" : 0,
                      "build_scorer_count" : 26,
                      "create_weight" : 3957,
                      "shallow_advance" : 0,
                      "create_weight_count" : 1,
                      "build_scorer" : 307522
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "rewrite_time" : 7897,
            "collector" : [
              {
                "name" : "CancellableCollector",
                "reason" : "search_cancelled",
                "time" : "45.1micros",
                "time_in_nanos" : 45124,
                "children" : [
                  {
                    "name" : "SimpleTopScoreDocCollector",
                    "reason" : "search_top_hits",
                    "time" : "22.1micros",
                    "time_in_nanos" : 22110
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "aggregations" : [ ]
      },
       .............
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run profiler in the search the total time of your query would be much higher than usual run, best way to check the total time is to run the query without profiler and compare the time with each node.